# BackroundWorker - Exception - Don't Close WinForms App

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a simple WinForms application running a `BackgroundWorker`.

Below is Main where I'm attaching Exception handlers.

```
static class Program
{
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.ThreadException += OnThreadException;
        //Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
       // AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        try
        {
            Application.Run(new Form());
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            LogFatalException(exc);
        }
    }

    private static void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsTerminating)
        {
            _logger.Info("Application is terminating due to an unhandled exception in a secondary thread.");
        }
        LogFatalException(e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
    }

    private static void OnThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        LogFatalException(e.Exception);
    }

    private static void LogFatalException(Exception exc)
    {
        _logger.Error(exc, exc.Message);

        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

I'm calling into my BackgroundWorker like so below. I want any type of exception that occurs on the background thread to bubble up to the Main handling methods and log/alert but NOT close the application down.

What am I doing wrong? The application is still closing down.

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += (senderWorker, eWorker) =>
{
    if (eWorker != null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error Processing. Please check connection and try again.");
    }
};

backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: If you don't catch that exception somewhere the framework will terminate the application.

Comment: Peter, can you be more specific based on the code I outlined? Where should I be catching the exception?

Comment: Why is the UnhandledException subscription remarked?

Comment: Why throw an exception at all?  In the Completed event you're on the UI thread, just update the UI with any error information.

Comment: eWorker would be a RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs object.  I can't image it would ever be null.

Comment: You never catch the exception you manually throw `throw new Exception("Error Processi...`.

Comment: The program is still bombing out regardless if I throw that exception in RunWorkerCompleted or not. I'm trying to capture the exception, log it, and keep the program open.

Comment: @aherrick have you took out of remark this: `// AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnUnhandledException;`? It should catch your unhandledexception

Answer (score 0):

If you let the exception bubble all the way up until it even leaves the `Application.Run()` call, then obviously this `Application` cannot run anymore, you caught the exception outside of the `Application`'s scope. You would need to catch the exception *inside* your `Form`.

But that is really not necessary here. When you arrive in your `RunWorkerCompleted` handler, you are already back on the UI thread. You can evaluate the result of the background process and display an adequate error message on your UI.

The `eWorker` argument of that handler is provided by the `BackgroundWorker` implementation. You are safe to rely on it never being `null`. What you might want to check is the `Result` property of `eWorker`. What this will be depends on what you set to the `Result` property of the `DoWorkEventArgs` you received as argument to your `DoWork` handler.

So for example:

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += (senderWorker, eWorker) =>
{
    if (eWorker.Result != null)
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Process result: " + eWorker.Result.ToString())
    }
}
```

and your `DoWork` handler could look like this:

```
backgroundWorker1.DoWork += (senderWorker, e) =>
{
    try
    {
        // do something that might throw an exception
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        e.Result = exception; // this result is passed on to RunWorkerCompleted event
    }
}
```